# Particular dynamical system having a bounded orbit

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems

I'm new to dynamical systems, but I've stumbled onto an interesting system and I'm wondering if the orbit is bounded or not for a particular initial condition.  The function in question is:
$f(x) = \begin{cases}
       \sqrt{x} &\quad\text{if }x \geq 2\\ 
       \frac{x}{2-x} &\quad \text{if } x < 2
     \end{cases} $
and initial condition $x_0 = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$.  Does anyone know if this has a bounded or dense orbit?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean if $x \ge 2$?

Comment: Math experiment done with Maple produces first 21 terms of the sequence $$\left[{\frac {1/2\,\sqrt {5}+1/2}{-1/2\,\sqrt {5}+3/2}},\sqrt {2},{\frac {
\sqrt {2}}{2-\sqrt {2}}},\sqrt {2},{\frac {\sqrt {2}}{2-\sqrt {2}}},
\sqrt {2},{\frac {\sqrt {2}}{2-\sqrt {2}}},\sqrt {2},{\frac {\sqrt {2}
}{2-\sqrt {2}}},\sqrt {2},{\frac {\sqrt {2}}{2-\sqrt {2}}},\sqrt {2},{
\frac {\sqrt {2}}{2-\sqrt {2}}},\sqrt {2},{\frac {\sqrt {2}}{2-\sqrt {
2}}},\sqrt {2},{\frac {\sqrt {2}}{2-\sqrt {2}}},\sqrt {2},{\frac {
\sqrt {2}}{2-\sqrt {2}}},\sqrt {2}\right]
 $$

Comment: @user64494 The first term simplified is 2 + sqrt(5), so the second term would need to be the square root of that and not sqrt(2).

Comment: @user64494 This sequence cannot have dense orbit as the function $\frac{x}{2-x}$ has zero as its attracting fixed point.Maybe you had in mind dense in the axis $[\sqrt{2},+\infty)$?

Comment: You are right. The adjusted result is $$[4.23606797749986, 2.05817102727151, 1.43463271511266, 2.53752340020618, 1.59296057710358, 3.91352897900738, 1.97826413277079, 91.0138119592614, 9.54011593007451, 3.08870780911282, -2.83704018953422, -.586524006079720, -.226761477837079, -.101834650946692, -0.484503625919501e-1, -0.236522024046728e-1, -0.116878791605432e-1, -0.580998637095753e-2, -0.289657864425599e-2, -0.144619481362171e-2]  $$ up  to 15 digits. In my previous comment I started from a different point $x_0$ than in the question: explanation, but not justification.

Comment: If I had to venture a guess: there's an invariant, ergodic probability measure supported on $[\sqrt{2},+\infty)$, which would imply that almost every orbit is dense. Idea : induce the system on $[\sqrt{2},2)$. Check that you get a topologically mixing uniformly expanding map with bounded distortion. There's a lot of small work to do however (uniform expansion is true at $\sqrt{2}$ and close to $2$, but I don't know if it's true everywhere).